# How to check if ID matches another ID and then display them via a foreach

Tags: c#, database, xna, foreach

not sure how to phrase this question, but I'll try anyway.

I'm currently working on a project where i want to pull out the user's highscore via. a highscore id in my database which would look something like this:

```
The user database:
|ID | Username |
| 1 | Test1    |
| 2 | Test2    |
| 3 | Test3    |

The highscore database:
|ID |Highscore |HighscoreID|
| 1 | 200      | 1         |
| 1 | 230      | 2         |
| 1 | 240      | 3         |
```

First, i wish to check if the the user's ID matches the ID in the highscore database (HighscoreID), so that when displaying all the highscores, Test1 (Whose ID is 1) will be displayed in front of the highscore which ID corresponds with the id in HighscoreID. Kind of like;

```
If(Username.ID == 1 && Highscore.HighscoreID == 1)
{
 //Display The username + the score associated with that username
}
```

I'm not sure how else to explain this, but when ever we wanted to display something via ID from websites, we would have the ID in the address link, and then just pull out everything with the ID from the address link.

I hope this was explained well enough, hitting a deadline soon with the game, so i hope i dont have to rewrite this question.

Thanks in advance, you guys rock.

*EDIT*

So basicly this:

```
 MathAndYouDBEntities db = new MathAndYouDBEntities();
            User users = new User();
            HighScore highscor = new HighScore();
            int idCounter = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                i = idCounter;
                if (users.ID == i && highscor.HighscoreID == i)
                { 

                }
            }
```

If i want to loop through all of them so i can display them later?

D

```
oing this basicly crashes the program:
   MathAndYouDBEntities db = new MathAndYouDBEntities();
            User users = new User();
            HighScore highscor = new HighScore();
            int idCounter = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                i = idCounter;
                if (users.ID == idCounter && highscor.HighscoreID == idCounter)
                {
                    allUsers += users.Bruger.ToString();
                    highscores += highscor.UserHighscore.ToString() + '\n';
                }
            }

            message = allUsers + " " + highscores;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really mean 'if (Username.ID == 1 && Highscore.HighscoreID == 1)', or didd you mean 'if (Username.ID == 1 && Highscore.ID == 1)', instead? How do you get your data from the database?

Comment: It was just an example of how the database looked. I had no idea on how to make it so i figured a little example on how i was thinking it should look would go a long way explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     If(Username.ID == 1 && Highscore.HighscoreID == 1)
     {
       System.out.println("Username is: " Username.name + "And the high score is :" + Highscore.Highscore);
       //Display The username + the score associated with that username
     }
```

Because if your checking the right username ID with the right highscore, you can use that same highscore to get the highscore out of it.

I hope I am making sense!

Edit: Sorry, I didn't read that you wanted it in a for loop

```
  for(Highscore h : HighscoreList)   //ifyourusinganarraylistnamedHighscoreList
   If(Username.ID == 1 && Highscore.HighscoreID == 1)
   {
            System.out.println("Username is: " Username.name + "And the high score is    :" + Highscore.Highscore);
   }
```

Comment: It seems i cant answer with code in the comment section, so i'll put it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using some sort of ORM you can do this.

```
var highScore = Highscores.Where(c => c.HighscoreID == 1)
                          .Max(c => c.Highscore);
```

Or do it in your query string.

Comment: Thats no really something that allows me to make a foreach around it. Its a list of all the highscores + the users who made them. Thanks though :)

Comment: "Its a list of all the highscores", as you say its a list. It means that whether it will be an array, dictionary or list?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to it after a lot of testing.

```
MathAndYouDBEntities db = new MathAndYouDBEntities();

            var queryResults =
                (
                from u in db.Users
                join h in db.HighScores
                on u.ID equals h.HighscoreID
                select new { u.Bruger, h.UserHighscore }
                );

            foreach (var h in queryResults)
            {
                allUsers += h.Bruger.ToString();
                highscores += h.UserHighscore.ToString();
            }
```

Thanks everyone for helping though.